# Getting Installation Issues With ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting following error while installed asp.net mvc. I tried searching on web but didn't find anything helpful yet.
Error I'm getting is

```
MSI (s) (C4:40) [20:45:32:977]: Note: 1: 1722 2: VisualStudio_VSSetup_Command 3: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe 4: /setup

MSI (s) (C4:40) [20:45:32:979]: Product: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC Beta -- Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action VisualStudio_VSSetup_Command, location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe, command: /setup

Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action VisualStudio_VSSetup_Command, location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe, command: /setup
```

and

```
Faulting application devenv.exe, version 9.0.30729.1, time stamp 0x488f2b50, faulting module unknown, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp 0x00000000, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x006c0061, process id 0x10e0, application start time 0x01c9355ee383bf70
```

I'm new to asp.net mvc, So I am not able to figure out what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the Issue after a little search on net .
Just by removing the add-ins before installing MVC, and then reinstalling the add-ins, will resolve the problem. 
ASP.NET MVC installations have been known to run into problems when the following add-ins were already installed.:

1. PowerCommands
2. Clone Detective